# How would I make a Timer which times things in 0.75 seconds Javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, timer, setinterval, console.log

Just wondering how I would make a timer which times in 0.75 seconds instead of an entire second. I already know how to make a 1 second timer.

```
var myTimer = setInterval(function(){ 

    console.log("This will appear every second");

}, 1000);
```

Thanks

Comment: Really poor research effort

Comment: if it says how to do it in 1s, don't you know how to do it in 0.75s..? simple mathematics.. :)

Comment: SORRY! My code wasn't working. I only started coding javascript today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second parameter of the setInterval function is the interval time in milliseconds - the 1000. Just change it to 750.

```
var myTimer = setInterval(function() {
    console.log("This will appear every 750 milliseconds"); 
}, 750);
```

Comment: Oh okay, I understand it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use 750 as value for the timeout delay

```
setInterval(/*...*/, 750);
```

Regards